# Trying to find the kth ancestor of a node in a tree by recursion but not able to get it

Tags: java, binary, binary-tree

I am trying to solve the GeeksForGeeks problem [Kth Ancestor in a Tree](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/kth-ancestor-in-a-tree/1):

> Given a binary tree of size  `N`, a `node`, and a positive integer `k`, your task is to complete the function `kthAncestor()`, the function should return the `k`<sup>th</sup> ancestor of the given node in the binary tree. If there does not exist any such ancestor then return -1.
>
> **Note:** It is guaranteed that the `node` exists in the tree.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - `1 <= N <= 104`
> - `1 <= K <= 100`

Here is my code:

```
class Tree
{
    public Node solve(Node root,int k,int node)
    {
        if(root==null)
            return null;
        if(root.data==node)
            return root;
        Node l=solve(root.left,k,node);
        Node r=solve(root.right,k,node);
        if(l!=null && r==null)
        {
            k--;
            if(k==0)
                return root;
            return l;
        }
        else if(r!=null && l==null)
        {
            k--;
            if(k==0)
                 return root;
            return r;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    public int kthAncestor(Node root, int k, int node)
    {
        //Write your code here
        if(root.data==node && k==0)
            return node;
        if(root.data==node && k>0)
            return -1;
        Node ans=solve(root,k,node);
        if(ans==null)
            return -1;
        else
            return ans.data;
    }
}
```

it is giving me incorrect answer for this test case:

[image]

Input:

```
 K = 2
 Node = 4
```

Expected Output: `1`

Output I get: `4`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your attempt is that `(k == 0)` will never be true when `k` is greater than 1. As `k` is a local variable, and all recursive calls get the same `k`, `k--` will just make `k` one less than the original value of `k`. On the other hand, if `k` is 1, it will always reach 0 when executing `k--`.

Not a problem, but if your code finds a match in the left subtree, it still goes on to search the right subtree, which is a waste of time.

Not your fault, but I find it unclear that the code challenge speaks of a node parameter and of returning a node, when in fact the function gets the *value* of a node to look for and wants you to return the *value* of the ancestor node. I would certainly rename the parameter variable from `node` to something else.

One of the difficulties here is that you need need to identify the found node *and* the depth it has from the current node. So either you could return an object that has those two properties, or use a class instance variable to keep track of the found node, and use the return value for the depth where the node was found.

If we would go with the second idea, the solution code could look like this:

```
class Tree
{
    int ancestor; // This will have the solution
    
    public int depthOf(Node root, int k, int needle)
    {
        if (root == null) return -1;

        if (root.data == needle) {
            if (k == 0) ancestor = root.data;
            return 0;
        }

        int depth = depthOf(root.left, k, needle);
        if (depth == -1) depth = depthOf(root.right, k, needle);
        if (depth == -1) return -1;

        depth++;
        if (depth == k) ancestor = root.data;
        return depth;
    }

    public int kthAncestor(Node root, int k, int needle)
    {
        ancestor = -1;
        depthOf(root, k, needle);
        return ancestor;
    }
}
```